# How to open terminal from terminal and run a program(script)?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, compiling, sublime-text

I recently started to program using Sublime Text 3 (I use gnome-terminal) and I was trying to make a script that compiles my C++ programs and runs them in a terminal window. I became making this script:

```
"cmd":["g++ src/*.cpp -o bin/debug/main && gnome-terminal -- ./bin/debug/main"]
```

*bin/debug/main is where my `main.o` is going to be saved*

When I actually run a program, sublime text is able to compile and run the program, but if I make a std::cin funtion he doesn't read that! For example, I have this code bellow:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int numb = 0;
    std::cout << "Yay we made it" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> numb;

    std::cout << "O seu numero é: " << numb << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I click F7 compiles perfectly and then shows the terminal but without the "**user@user_pc $**" and only shows my first `cout` with the `endl` and it appears to be waiting for the user `numb` input:

```
Yay we made it
```

But when I put a random number (e.g. 10) and press *ENTER* the window closes and doesn't show the final result.

So my problem is how do I keep the terminal window open so I can execute the in-program commands?

PS: I've also tried with xterm but I've got the same results.

Comment: PopOS isn't Ubuntu, and isn't supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @waltinator but PopOS is built over Ubuntu, just a different apppearence, all works exactly the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom profile in GNOME Terminal that does not close the window and use that profile to launch the terminal window.

In Preferences, define a new profile (let's call it `noclose`) and in the "Command" tab, choose the option to keep the window open after the command finishes. Then, use the option `--window-with-profile=noclose` in the `gnome-terminal` command before `--`.

Alternatively, just put one more `std::cin` at the end of your program that reads some completely unused variable.

Comment: Your second alternative helped, but when I did the first thing it still did the same thing (maybe i did something wrong, i did this: `g++ src/*.cpp -o bin/debug/main && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=noclose -- ./bin/debug/main`)! Thank you very much!

Comment: Probably you did something wrong when defining the profile `noclose`.

Comment: I the profile was defined correctly, i think the issue is with the command itself!

Comment: Check what `man gnome-terminal` says - maybe in your system you need to use a different parameter form.